# Pause Request Listening when app goes to background

Tags: android, fragment, robospice

I am building an Android app using Robospice v1.4.9. In OnRequestSuccess(), I am trying to commit a fragment transaction. The problem happens when I call the service and while waiting for the response, I put my application to background. As I put my app to background, It saves the state of the activity by calling OnSavedInstanceState(). Meanwhile if the service response comes then OnRequestSuccess() gets called and app thorws IllegalStateException while committing the fragment transaction as fragment transactions cannot be committed after the state of the activity has been saved.

So I want that when my app goes to the background, the request listening should be paused and when my activity comes to foreground, request listening should be resumed. Is it possible with Robospice ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this in-depth explanation of the problem : http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

It's not related to RS per say, but to fragment life cycles.